# perl telnet connection checking

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm using the below code for connecting to telnet with host and ip address, but its giving me an error saying "Can't call method "write" on an undefined value at  at line "
But when i try to connect to the host and ip address manually its working.

How can i make sure whether the telnet connection is working or not?
Any help?

```
$ip = 14.12.345.32
$ip_port=12345
$port1 = new Net::Telnet->new( Host=>$ip,Port=>$ip_port, Timeout => 100, Errmode => 'return');
$port1->write("\n");
```

Comment: What is the line number in error?

Comment: There is a "\n" which i'm writing just after connecting telnet. as "$port1->write("\n"); ... which is the line failing.

Comment: You should show the complete code with error message. It would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply and have edited and added the code. The issue is like 1 out of 5 attempts the connection fails, not always and i get the error. How do i test that?

Comment: I guess instead of `write` use `print`, change last line with `$write = $port1->print("\n");` and also remove one `new` from second last line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one "new". I prefer

```
$ip = 14.12.345.32;
$ip_port=12345;
$port1 = Net::Telnet->new( Host=>$ip,Port=>$ip_port, Timeout => 100, Errmode => 'return');
```

Of course, don't forget the use statement and the use strict and use warnings (and the semi-colons at the end of the lines).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried it and it is like it doesn't work sometimes, like 1 out of 5 attempts the connection fails. How do i test that?